# What is the difference between rich:autocomplete and rich:suggestionbox

Tags: java, richfaces

I've been searching the web but I found no clear explanations. I am trying to find out what is the difference between the rich:autocomplete and rich:suggestionbox functionalities.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<rich:autocomplete>` is a richfaces 4 component and `<rich:suggestionBox>` is a richfaces 3 component. As described in the [richfaces 3 to richfaces 4 migration guide](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RichFacesMigrationGuide33x-4xMigration-ComponentsMigration-RichInputComponents), `<rich:autocomplete>` combines the features of `<rich:suggestionBox>` and `<rich:comboBox>` components from richfaces 3.

**See also:**

- [richfaces 3 documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/)
- [richfaces 4 components documentation](http://www.jboss.org/richfaces/docs/4-0_comp_reference)

Comment: Thanks, and I see from that website that <rich:autocomplete> is a merge of <rich:suggestionBox> and <rich:comboBox>.